# GDI Replace drawing after set another value in TrackBar

Tags: c#, gdi, trackbar

I want to draw a figure that will change shape when I move the track bar to a different value. For example for value=1
[image: pic1]

Next I draw for second figure for value=2

[image: pic2]

I want only one shape. What should I do? Shape should change in every value of Track Bar. Here some my code for DrawTickedCircle:

```
private void DrawTickedCircle(Graphics gr, Pen circle_pen, Pen tick_pen,float cx, float cy, float rx, float ry,
                float num_theta, float num_ticks, float tick_fraction)
{
    List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();

    float dalpha = (float)(2 * Math.PI / num_theta);
    float alpha = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_theta; i++)
    {
        float x = (float)(cx + rx * Math.Cos(alpha));
        float y = (float)(cy + ry * Math.Sin(alpha));
        points.Add(new PointF(x, y));
        alpha += dalpha;
    }
    gr.DrawPolygon(circle_pen, points.ToArray());

    dalpha = (float)(2 * Math.PI / num_ticks);
    alpha = 0;

    float rx1 = rx * (1 - tick_fraction);
    float ry1 = ry * (1 - tick_fraction);

    for (int k = 0; k < num_ticks; k++)
    {
        float x1 = (float)(cx + rx * Math.Cos(alpha));
        float y1 = (float)(cy + ry * Math.Sin(alpha));
        float x2 = (float)(cx + rx1 * Math.Cos(alpha));
        float y2 = (float)(cy + ry1 * Math.Sin(alpha));
        gr.DrawLine(tick_pen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
        alpha += dalpha;
    }
}
```

For trackBarScroll function:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

    float cx = ClientRectangle.Width / 2;
    float cy = ClientRectangle.Height / 2;
    float rx = Math.Min(cx, cy);
    float ry = rx;

    rx *= 0.8f;
    ry *= 0.6f;

    if (trackBar1.Value == 1)
    {
        DrawTickedCircle(g, Pens.Black, Pens.Black, cx, cy, rx, ry, 8, 8, 0.1F);
    }
    else if (trackBar1.Value == 2)
    {
        DrawTickedCircle(g, Pens.Red, Pens.Red, cx, cy, rx, ry, 255, 255, 0.1f);
    }
    g.Dispose();
}
```

I don't want draw these in PaintEvent. Thanks for help!

Comment: You need to repaint the figure when the calculations are completed.  So do the calculations and then repaint the g object.

Comment: Use the paint event of the container to do your drawing.  Don't use CreateGraphics.  `var g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();`  is a temporary drawing, and will be erased by simply minimizing and restoring the form.  Use `e.Graphics.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor);` at the beginning of your paint routine to clear the control.

Answer (score -1):

This answer might be a few days late, but to answer your question: you should invalidate the control and force it to repaint it immediately when the value is changed. This can be done by the `Refresh` method. Add the following line into your Scroll event of your trackbar before you create the `Graphics` object.

```
pictureBox1.Refresh();
```